# ValueTuple in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, c#-7.0, valuetuple

It seems like Razor doesn't understand the `ValueTuple`. In my Razor page:

```
@{
     var x = (1, "a");
}
```

The code above gives me:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

[image]

I tried the same code in my controller and it's working, I already added the following in my `csproj`:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.3.0" />
```

**UPDATE**

I added this but still not working:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="2.1.0" />
```

Comment: Do other C# 7 features work within Razor? I wonder whether you need to add a package for the C# compiler itself... Try `object o = null; if (o is string x) {}`

Comment: I'll try, hang on.

Comment: @JonSkeet No they aren't. I tried `var d = 0xAB_CD_EF;` and the code you gave me.

Comment: Try to add the [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) for your project

Comment: VMAtm can only be used with Full Framework.  Nuget has that pasted at the top of the package description.

Comment: @VMAtm I tried it, not working.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you need to add a newer Compilers package, you also need to configure Razor options.

See previous answer: [Using C# 7 features inside of a View in an ASP.NET MVC Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844341/using-c-sharp-7-features-inside-of-a-view-in-an-asp-net-mvc-core-project/42944604#42944604)